# ASP.NET Core 7 add-migration build failed

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-7.0

This error is really starting to annoy me. When I try to `add-migrate` in VS, it tells me the build failed.

The problem is that it worked a few minutes ago.

[image]

I faced this error a few weeks ago but I just rage quit, shut down my laptop, came back a few days later and it worked for whatever reason.

So I tried to shut down my laptop, rebuild the solution.

The migration folder is empty because I was trying to solve an fk constraint error so I kept deleting the migration files.

But it always refilled the migration folder... not anymore because I get this build failed error. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to press
Ctrl+Shift+B
then it showed me the errors and then i could migrate

Answer (score 0):

It works again
I went to my data folder removed some code and added it again.
I didn't change the code.
and the error also went away.

Code is working and not working at random.